# MySQL Grouping Datetime when using SUM

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm using this MySQL query to add traffic records in 15minute groupings.

```
    SELECT SUM(bytes), ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_end)/(15 * 60)) AS timekey 
      FROM acct_v9 
  GROUP BY timekey
```

My 'timestamp_end' column is stored as a datetime, however when I try to convert this query back to the datetime, using `FROM_UNIXTIME` I keep getting dates in 1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide and round timestamp, you don't obtain a valid timestamp. You have to re-multiply it by (15*60):

```
    SELECT COUNT(*), 
           SUM(bytes), 
           ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_end)/(15 * 60))*(15*60) AS timekey
      FROM acct_v9 
  GROUP BY timekey
```

By this query you will obtain valid timestamps.

To obtain directly a formatted date, you can use this query:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*), 
          SUM(bytes), 
          FROM_UNIXTIME
          (
            ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_end)/(15 * 60))*(15*60)
            ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
          ) AS timekey
     FROM acct_v9 
 GROUP BY timekey
```

<kbd>**[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb099/10)**</kbd>

Obviously, you can change `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` with your desired format.

Comment: Thank you, this got the results I was looking for. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the need for the extra multiplication step?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT SUM(bytes),DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_end), '%e %b %Y') AS timekey 
    FROM acct_v9 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_end), '%e %b %Y')
```

Comment: Isn't `FROM_UNIXTIME` is for converting a timestamp to a date? My "timestamp_end" column is inserted into the DB already using FROM_UNIXTIME. Then the ROUND function converts it back to a timestamp to do the math. I'm trying to get it back to the numeric date format which was inserted into the DB.